# export datatable from c# to pdf

Tags: c#, pdf

I have a list of tables that i export it from c# to PDF

```
List<DataTable> l;
```

I want to do contents that contain: table name and the number of page that the table begin

how I do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How I can export a datatable to excel 2007 and pdf from asp.net?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669613/how-i-can-export-a-datatable-to-excel-2007-and-pdf-from-asp-net)

Comment: no, i need to do contents.

Answer (score 0):

Try iTextSharp + export dataTable as pdf
http://amin-sayed.blogspot.com/2008/10/in-this-article-ill-demonstrate-how-to.html

Answer (score 0):

Refer this, if you get some needful..

[Export Data to Excel, Word, PDF without Automation](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/151789/Export-Data-to-Excel-Word-PDF-without-Automation-f)

Comment: Take this link down